# Cygwin printf double variable seems to waste memory

Tags: printf, double, cygwin

I try to run a simple program that print a double value in infinite loop. When monitoring I see that memory increase from few Mb to 1 Gb!?
I run it under CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045 DESKTOP-U1587BG 3.4.7-1.x86_64 2023-06-16 14:04 UTC x86_64 Cygwin (last version)
gcc (GCC) 11.4.0

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a=1.283;
    while(1)
    printf( "%f", a );
}
```

Comment: Try to print a newline every once in a while.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330643, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45385807/11082165

Comment: Seems an error of Cygwin system also with g++ cout done the same wate memory